# Excel saying too many arguments for IF/AND/MONTH function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need it to produce orders that are in Canada or Mexico, over $1,000, and in the month of July. The formula I am trying to use is:

```
=IF(OR(A2="Canada","Mexico", IF(C2>1000, "Ship by Air", IF(MONTH(B2=7, "Ship by Air", "Ship by Ground")))
```

I don't know how else to write it with all of that information.

Answer (score 3):

`OR` needs each part to be its own Boolean expression:

> `OR(A2="Canada","Mexico"`

Should be:

```
OR(A2="Canada",A2="Mexico")
```

OR

```
OR(A2={"Canada","Mexico"})
```

And

> `MONTH(B2`

is missing the `)`

So:

```
=IF(OR(A2={"Canada","Mexico"}), IF(C2>1000, "Ship by Air", IF(MONTH(B2)=7, "Ship by Air", "Ship by Ground")))
```

Also you are missing the FALSE on the outer IF, which may be what you want, but I tend to add it so my formulas are more readable:

```
=IF(OR(A2={"Canada","Mexico"}), IF(C2>1000, "Ship by Air", IF(MONTH(B2)=7, "Ship by Air", "Ship by Ground")),FALSE)
```

But we can combine the inner two as the output is the same on the true:

```
=IF(OR(A2={"Canada","Mexico"}), IF(OR(C2>1000, MONTH(B2)=7), "Ship by Air", "Ship by Ground"),FALSE)
```

---

Edit:  this will return `Ship by Air` if any of the following are TRUE:

- A2 equals "Canada" or "Mexico"
- C2 > 1000
- The Month of B2 is July

:

```
=IF(OR(A2={"Canada","Mexico"},C2>1000, MONTH(B2)=7), "Ship by Air", "Ship by Ground")
```

---

Edit2:  this will return `Ship by Air` if All of the following are TRUE:

- A2 equals "Canada" or "Mexico"
- C2 > 1000
- The Month of B2 is July

:

```
=IF(AND(OR(A2={"Canada","Mexico"}),C2>1000, MONTH(B2)=7), "Ship by Air", "Ship by Ground")
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got a good start; your formula is "pseudo-code" for what you want to accomplish.  You just need to structure it for Excel.

The first problem is that the factors used by functions need to be enclosed in parentheses so Excel knows where they start and end.  Your first OR doesn't have a close parenthesis; the same with the MONTH function.

The second problem is that the OR needs to contain a choice of complete conditions.  Excel doesn't handle comparisons to a list, at least in a non-array format like you're using.

Also, the first IF doesn't contain a result for what to show if the OR is false, so you probably want to add that.

So the formula should look like:

```
=IF(OR(A2="Canada",A2="Mexico"), IF(C2>1000, "Ship by Air", IF(MONTH(B2)=7, "Ship by Air", "Ship by Ground")),"Not Canada or Mexico")
```

Comment: Okay, that one worked for the most part, however the orders from USA are coming up as false rather than "ship by ground" for some reason.

Comment: @Anna so what you are saying is if A2 is canada or Mexico or c2>1000 or the month in B2 is July, if any of those are true then ship by air?

Comment: @Anna, yeah, I had spotted the problem with no false result for the OR, then forgot why I included it in the answer and deleted it.  Need more coffee.  :-)  I added that back in.  You can change that last result to whatever you need (even another nested IF if the result could be something other than USA).

Comment: @Anna, Scott raises a good point.  You've got some complex rules for when to ship by what method.  The safe bet would be to expand the question with the complete set of rules for what you want to do (in words or a table).  Then we can verify that the Excel logic is actually implementing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Count the brackets:** You have five opening brackets and three closing brackets. But the counts have to match.

You can see the problem with correct indenting of the expression:

```
=IF(
    OR(
       A2="Canada","Mexico", 
       IF(
          C2>1000, "Ship by Air", 
          IF(
             MONTH(
                   B2=7, "Ship by Air", "Ship by Ground"
             )
          )
       )
// ---------------- Here your expression ends
    )    // missing
)        // missing
```

I marked the two missing closing brackets. Which expressions your want to close with `)` depends on the logic you want to implement.

Comment: So I just need to add more closing parentheses? I just tried that, so now there are 5 opening and 5 ending, but it is giving me the same error message.

Comment: A quick glance at [the Office documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MONTH-function-579A2881-199B-48B2-AB90-DDBA0EBA86E8) shows that the `MONTH(...)` function takes one argument. You provided three :-/ So remove `=7, "Ship by Air", "Ship by Ground"` and you should be closer to a working expression. Remember to also check the `IF` and `OR` clauses this way, because it looks like the second `IF` clause is also wrong, because it seems to need three arguments. See [IF clause](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69AED7C9-4E8A-4755-A9BC-AA8BBFF73BE2).